# USB-C to 15V conversion

Tags: usb-c

I need to be able to power a device that accepts 15V with a USB-C cable.
The issue is not physical but the wiring.
I know USB-C can deliver 15V. But how ? 
Do I simply need to wire the two wires to some specific pins on the usb cable ? Or do I need to add something ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check the [USB-C standard](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/sales_and_marketing/presentation/product_presentation/group0/5a/b1/8e/6c/2b/0d/46/3c/Apec/files/APEC_2016_USB_Power.pdf/_jcr_content/translations/en.APEC_2016_USB_Power.pdf).

USB-C by default provides 5V, you need to communicate with the supply source through the CC line to get higher voltage.

I think it would be quite complex to do it and the best way is probably to use a chip that does it for you. Unfortunately, since USBC is relatively new, it might be difficult to find.

Given that, also it wouldn't work with all usb-c supply, you would need a supply that is able to supply 15V, which is probably not the case for all.

All that said, if you want 15V off a USB supply, as long as the power is enough, it would be easier to use 5V with a boost converter to reach 15V.

Comment: Thanks. If I use 5V then I dont need to add a chip right ? And where do I find a boost converter 5 》 15 ?

Comment: It depends on the current needed from 5V. According to the standert, unconfigured device is allowed to get only 100 mA. But usually, it can drain up to 500 mA (but it will not conform to the standart, if configuration is not performed).

Answer (score 3):

You need to incorporate a USB-C controller into your device which creates a bridge between the microcontroller in the device (e.g. I2C interface) and the CC lines in the USB cable. There are already breakout boards and Arduino code around for rapid prototyping, e.g. https://github.com/ReclaimerLabs/USB-PD-Breakout